# SpringBoot repository find response time increases with many concurrent calls, while manual database search not affected

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, groovy

I am trying to improve the response time of my REST APIs (I am using SpringBoot 2.1.3 with Groovy 2.4.14 and MSSQL).  I noticed that the more popular GET API are at certain time periods taking much longer than they should be (>4 seconds as opposed to 0.3 seconds).  I've looked into CPU usage, memory, blocking threads, blocking DBs, DeferredResult, fetching schemes, SpringBoot and JPA settings, etc none of these were a bottleneck or were just not relevant (the database search is a simple repository.findById() for a domain object with a few primitive fields).

> ```
> List<Object> getObjectForId(String id) {
>     curCallCount++
>     List<Object> objList = objectRepository.findAllById(id)
>     curCallCount--
>     objList
> }
> ```

The issue seems to be that the more existing calls to the service that have not exited at the time of the call, the longer the response time of the API call (there is almost a linear correlation, if there are 50 existing calls to the service, repository.findbyId() takes 5 seconds, and if there are 200, it would take 20 seconds.  Meanwhile while there are 200 concurrent calls, the manual database query is still fast (0.3 seconds).

Is this expected for the Spring repository calls?  Where is this overhead from repository.findById() coming from in an environment when there are many concurrent calls to the service, even though the manual database search performance is not affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the Hikari pool size being too small (10 by default, so that when there are more than 10 concurrent calls, processes must wait for a free thread).  Increasing this (to 150, for example) resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the API side, but I would certainly start by looking at the compilation/recompilation rate in SQL Server and looking at your plan cache usage.  Using a string variable might be passing all your parameters in as nvarchar(max) and limiting the reuse of your query plans.

Comment: I've checked the SQL Profiler for recompile events, but there doesn't seem to be that many.  However, as per the Hibernate general_statistics logs, it seems like the time to get the jdbc connection increases quickly with the number of connections in the function:
  (1 connection to repository.findById(): 0.09 seconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections - 80 concurrent calls to repository.findById(): 7.1 seconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections)  Is this normal?  Even with the load of 80 calls, the manual query to the database is fast and takes no time to acquire a connection to the database.